# error when running yarn watch with a tensorflowjs project

Tags: angular, ubuntu, yarnpkg, tensorflow.js

I am using ubuntu 18 with yarn and node v 8.11.3
When running the example here
With the following shell commands

```
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-examples
cd tfjs-examples/webcam-transfer-learning
yarn
yarn watch
```

I am getting the following error when getting to the last line of code:

> yarn run v1.9.4 $ cross-env NODE_ENV=development parcel index.html
>   --no-hmr --open Server running at http://localhost:1234 hourglass_flowing_sand Building asyncToGenerator.js... events.js:183
>   throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event ^
>
> Error: watch
>   /home/user/WebstormProjects/tfjs-examples/webcam-transfer-learning/node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.math.fround.js
>   ENOSPC at _errnoException (util.js:992:11) at FSWatcher.start
>   (fs.js:1382:19) at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1408:11) at
>   createFsWatchInstance
>   (/home/user/WebstormProjects/tfjs-examples/webcam-transfer-learning/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:37:15)
>   at setFsWatchListener
>   (/home/user/WebstormProjects/tfjs-examples/webcam-transfer-learning/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:80:15)
>   at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs
>   (/home/user/WebstormProjects/tfjs-examples/webcam-transfer-learning/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:232:14) at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._handleFile
>   (/home/uwer/WebstormProjects/tfjs-examples/webcam-transfer-learning/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:259:21) at FSWatcher.
>   (/home/user/WebstormProjects/tfjs-examples/webcam-transfer-learning/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:480:21) at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:5) error Command failed with exit
>   code 1. info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for
>   documentation about this command.

I had no luck finding anything about it.
I tried changing the tfjs version with no luck
I upgraded Node, and tried to downgrade it to earlier stable versions.
We tried running this on a windows machine, and it worked.

We tried using the same versions that are working on a windows machine: npm 8.10 & yarn 5.04 with no luck

What might be the issue here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using the following two command in terminal solved the problem, I really don't know why, can anyone help me explain?

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
sudo sysctl --system
```

then

```
yarn 
yarn watch
```

works beautifully

Thanks!

Comment: You are overriding the kernel settings, the error may be because you need more/less watchers than the max your kernel allows (im just supposing). The same thing happened to me with Ubuntu x64.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use:

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json yarn.lock
npm cache clear --force
npm install
yarn watch
```

Solved for me!